# Convert string of coordinates into an array of CLLocations in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, cllocation

I have a string with a list of coordinates that I need to convert into an array. I tried to do `let array = Array(coordinates)` but it says `String` no longer conforms to `SequenceType`. I need to convert the string to an array of `CLLocations`. The string I am trying to convert looks like this:

```
let coordinates = "[[39.86475483576405,-75.53281903266907], [39.864688955564304,-75.53292632102966], [39.86455719497505,-75.53300142288208], [39.86440072894666,-75.5330228805542], [39.8642689678039,-75.53295850753784], [39.863305456757146,-75.53223967552185], [39.86303369478483,-75.53266882896423]]"
```

Comment: Do you have control over the format of that string or is it something you are stuck with?

Comment: @rmaddy I am stuck with this format

Comment: `String` -> `Data` -> `JSONSerialization` -> `[[Double]]` -> `map` -> `[CLLocation]`

Comment: @vadian, `string` -> `Data` -> `JSONSerialization` is superb :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is a valid JSON string.

The most straightforward way is to deserialize the string with `JSONSerialization` and map the result to `[CLLocation]`

```
let coordinates = "[[39.86475483576405,-75.53281903266907], [39.864688955564304,-75.53292632102966], [39.86455719497505,-75.53300142288208], [39.86440072894666,-75.5330228805542], [39.8642689678039,-75.53295850753784], [39.863305456757146,-75.53223967552185], [39.86303369478483,-75.53266882896423]]"

if let data = coordinates.data(using: .utf8),
    let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[Double]] {
    let locationArray  = jsonArray!.map{CLLocation(latitude:$0[0], longitude:$0[1]) }
    print(locationArray)

}
```

Comment: Oh, sure. Do it the easy way. Cheater. :) Though I'm not sure why you made good use of `try?` and `as?` only to force unwrap `jsonArray` on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to strip all of the brackets and spaces and then split the comma separated numbers into an array. Then convert each pair of number strings into numbers and finally create a `CLLocation` from the pair of numbers.

```
// Your string
let coordinates = "[[39.86475483576405,-75.53281903266907], [39.864688955564304,-75.53292632102966], [39.86455719497505,-75.53300142288208], [39.86440072894666,-75.5330228805542], [39.8642689678039,-75.53295850753784], [39.863305456757146,-75.53223967552185], [39.86303369478483,-75.53266882896423]]"
// Remove the brackets and spaces
let clean = coordinates.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\[\\] ]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
// Split the comma separated strings into an array
let values = clean.components(separatedBy: ",")
var coords = [CLLocation]()
for i in stride(from: 0, to: values.count, by: 2) {
    // Pull out each pair and convert to Doubles
    if let lat = Double(values[i]), let long = Double(values[i+1]) {
        let coord = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        coords.append(coord)
    }
}
```